# Check wallet balance via API

Tags: stellar-sdk

How could I check Stellar wallet balance using API? For example with BTC one can check address in block explorer and see the balance. I also need to differentiate incoming transactions by MEMO.

I looked some transactions examples, but still I'm confused. Where can I find any examples of balance check also considering MEMOs?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no single endpoint in horizon API that allows you to check the account's balance and/ or filtered by memo at the same time. If you want to differentiate incoming transactions by memo, what you can do is to use event streaming transactions for a particular account to extract the memo and consider injecting your logic in there, let me know what you want to exactly achieve. sample code using the javascript sdk below:

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

var notifyAccount = 'GATGC7IEHN6SBRPTEGIACCWXB6VHGVA7UYZGOIBE4LFXRSKYCLWO5QH3';

var txHandler = function (txResponse) {    
    console.log("new transaction activity");
    //get memo here
    console.log('memo: ' + txResponse.memo);
    console.log('memo_type: ' + txResponse.memo_type);
    server.accounts().accountId(notifyAccount)
        .call()
        .then(function (result) {
            //check balance here
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result.balances, null, 2));
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
}

console.log("listening for transactions to address " + notifyAccount);
var transStream = server.transactions()
    .cursor('now')
    .forAccount(notifyAccount)
    .stream({
        onmessage: txHandler
    });
```

OUTPUT:

```
listening for transactions to address GATGC7IEHN6SBRPTEGIACCWXB6VHGVA7UYZGOIBE4L
FXRSKYCLWO5QH3
new transaction activity
memo: testnow
memo_type: text
[
  {
    "balance": "0.0000000",
    "limit": "10000.0000000",
    "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "asset_code": "PHP",
    "asset_issuer": "GDENQQVYYVD4DWAF5243RLRW4GS7H2LAUM4VVRA2KDERFKP4N2XATCIJ"
  },
  {
    "balance": "2000.0000000",
    "limit": "10000.0000000",
    "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "asset_code": "USD",
    "asset_issuer": "GD5SBDV5OXBPSIDOQ6HGBNRE67ASQ6RHHYVXG7R7ZVGPM4AEYMT6BD7L"
  },
  {
    "balance": "0.0000000",
    "limit": "10000.0000000",
    "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "asset_code": "USD",
    "asset_issuer": "GDENQQVYYVD4DWAF5243RLRW4GS7H2LAUM4VVRA2KDERFKP4N2XATCIJ"
  },
  {
    "balance": "406.1607919",
    "asset_type": "native"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pick a horizon server to query (e.g., https://horizon.stellar.org/).  Then for account balances you want the [Account endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/accounts-single.html), which you can query like this:

```
curl https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GDOZSTU2PMCVID4TYBMMES6IDBO7SYBQY366S4VSK6SG2AS2R44RLIUH
```

(but substitute a real account account).  You'll find the balances in the balances field of the json object.

To get the transactions for your account, check the documentation on the [Transactions for account endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/transactions-for-account.html).  You will have to filter for memo yourself, but this should not be hard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete method to check balance of an address:

```
const checkBalance = async (publicKey) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const account = await server.loadAccount(publicKey);
            let balances = [];
            account.balances.forEach(function (balance) {
                balances.push(balance);
            });
            resolve(balances);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    })
}
```

Response will be:

```
{
            "balance": "9979.9999800",
            "buying_liabilities": "0.0000000",
            "selling_liabilities": "0.0000000",
            "asset_type": "native"
        }
```